# Rails- Create action does not saving record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a web project in Rails. There has a movies, books and series and users can write reviews about them. I created review_controller and inside that i created new action but action does not working. In the view side I use simple_form. The page of new_review_path is coming but record does not save in database. And also update action does not working either.

reviews_controller.erb

```
    class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  @review = Review.new
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end

  def show
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    if @review.save
      redirect_to action: 'index'
    else
      render :new, notice: 'Error.'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])

    if @review.update(review_params)
      redirect_to @review
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center mt-5">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h1>New Review</h1>

      <%= simple_form_for @review do |f| %>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :title %><br>
          <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
          <% @review.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
            <div style="color: red;"><%= message %></div>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.label :content, class: 'mt-4' %><br>
          <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %>
          <% @review.errors.full_messages_for(:content).each do |message| %>
            <div style="color: red;"><%= message %></div>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-primary mt-4' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-5">
      <%= simple_form_for @review do |form| %>
        <div>
          <%= form.label :title %><br>
          <%= form.text_field :title %>
          <% @review.errors.full_messages_for(:title).each do |message| %>
            <div><%= message %></div>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= form.label :content %><br>
          <%= form.text_area :content %><br>
          <% @review.errors.full_messages_for(:content).each do |message| %>
            <div><%= message %></div>
          <% end %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= form.submit %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'reviews/index'
  get 'reviews/new'
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'
  resources :reviews
end
```

Comment: Your issue is likely that a `Review` "belongs_to" a `User` and one of the following `Movie`, `Book`, `Series`, but you have not set these associations. As of Rails 5 belongs_to is validated by default so the save fails and it re-renders the new page; however these errors are "hidden" from you since you are only displaying the errors for :title and :content.

Comment: you're right. I solve this by ```belongs_to :user, optional: true``` doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem doing by `belongs_to :user, optional: true` After Rails 5, user association need to be this relation.